# How to get all IP addresses fetched

Tags: python, c++, ip, web-crawler, fetch

I have a bunch of websites, I want to find all the IP addresses that they communicate with while we browse them. For example once we browse Yahoo.com, it contacts several destinations until it is getting loaded.

Is there any library in the C++ or Python that can help me?
One way that I'm thinking about is to get the HTML file of the website and look for the format "src = http://", but it is not quite correct.

Comment: @jervis (too low rep to comment) asks: `Why do you think it's not correct?`

Comment: One major issue with this is the fact that many modern web apps reference scripts and use CSS to add elements to the page that may be sourced from elsewhere. Parsing *just* the HTML may not be enough.

Comment: The 'best' answer is likely a web proxy; although this isn't a programmatic approach, have you tried out [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: Yes I checked Fiddler (see comment on Jervis's answer), but I need to check 1000 websites, so it should be done automatically rather than manually

Comment: In that case, parsing out `src` and `href` attributes as jervis said might be sufficient (if not 100% perfect).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with http, urllib or urllib2.
You have to look for "src=" (images, flash etc.) and for "href=" (hyperlinks).
Why do you think it's not correct?

Comment: Two things - 1) like I referenced in one of my comments to the question, parsing out just `src` and `href` attributes from the generated HTML may not give the whole picture, as you miss out on elements added via CSS or scripting. And 2) your last sentence is better suited as a comment to the question (answers shouldn't be used in place of comments/discussion), which I have added as a comment for you due to your low rep.

Comment: When I check a website with Fiddler it shows that the website communicates with more destinations than those I extracted in HTML file. Also I need the number of contacts on each destination (REQUESTS PER HOST).